# Table vertical alignment webkit issue

Tags: html, css, html-table

Given the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/z4m7r/

HTML:

```
<table class="main-table" cellspacing="20">
    <tr>
        <td style="height:100%;"><table class="sub-table"><tr><td>Some text</td></tr><tr><td class="bottom-align">Some bottom aligned element</td></tr></table></td>
        <td>Some very long text. Some very long text. Some very long text. Some very long text. Some very long text. Some very long text. </td>
        <td>Some other text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.main-table {

    width:300px; 
    vertical-align: top;
}

.main-table td {

    vertical-align: top; 
}

.sub-table {

    height:100%;
}

td {

    border:2px solid black;
}

td.bottom-align {

    vertical-align: bottom;
    background:yellow;
}
```

The yellow cell text should be vertically aligned at the bottom. This works on Firefox but not on Safari / Chrome (webkit) browsers.

Any idea how I can achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First off: Why are you using tables and nested tables at that? Is this really for tabluar data?

To your problem: Webkit most likely abides strictly by the CSS rules for [height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height), which says, that height in per cent only applies if the containing block has an explicit height.

That means that you need to give the main-table a height (the height of a cell/row is explicitly calculated from the height of the table and the other cells/rows in the table). And if that is in turn in per cent, then also the next parent (here `body`), and so forth.

So either something like

```
.main-table { height: 500px; }
```

or

```
html, body, .main-table { height: 100%; }
```

will help.

(BTW, the `height: 100%` on the cell makes no sense.)

Comment: I can't believe I missed the fact the table didn't have height set.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to fill the space with padding:

```
td.bottom-align {
    padding-top:100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z4m7r/11/

**--EDIT--**

Set the parent table at 100% height and it should do the trick. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z4m7r/9/

Comment: This works if the middle cell with the "Very long text" is really like twice the size of the left cells. If not, then the padding-top:100%; creates a gap at the bottom of the middle cell. See http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/z4m7r/8/

Comment: Try my edit. You need to set your parent table at 100% height.

Comment: Seems to work. I need to test that a bit further. I will accept your answer if it works as expected! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4m7r/6/

To start with, I wouldn't use a table inside of another table as it will make the markup a nightmare to read and maintain.  It's also difficult to put one row at the bottom of the table and the other at the bottom.  Instead I just put two divs inside the cell:

```
<td class="firstcell" style="height:200px;">
    <div>Some text</div>
    <div class="bottom">Some bottom aligned text</div>
</td>
```

Next, I set the position of the parent cell to relative, and made the bottom div absolute:

```
.firstcell {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

.firstcell > div {
    border: solid thin black;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: yellow;
}
```